# Is there any way to transfer data say variable defined in inappbrowser and pass its value in executeScript method?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I want to use variable defined in inAppBrowser of cordova and use it in in executeScript method?

```
ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(env,'_blank','clearcache=no,location=no,
clearsessioncache=no, footer=no,zoom=no' );

var variable_needed = 1;

ref.addEventListener("loadstop", function(e) { ref.executeScript({
                    code: "console.log(variable_needed);"})
});
```

When I am trying to access varible_in executescript, it gives NULL.

I know they are different javascript bundle. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

The value passed via the `code` key of `executeScript()` is passed as a string to the Java layer which injects it into the Webview of the Inappbrowser and `eval()`'s it.
As such, there is no direct "connection" between the Cordova app Webview and the InappBrowser Webview that would allow Javascript entities to be directly shared.
Since the data is passed as a string, only stringifiable Javascript data can be passed (i.e. not functions).

In your case above, the variable value should simply be inlined in the code string:

```
ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(env,'_blank','clearcache=no,location=no, clearsessioncache=no, footer=no,zoom=no' );

var variable_needed = 1;

ref.addEventListener("loadstop", function(e) { 
    ref.executeScript({
        code: "console.log("+variable_needed+");"
    });
});
```

However if you want to send a more complex object structure you would need to stringify it, for example:

```
ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(env,'_blank','clearcache=no,location=no, clearsessioncache=no, footer=no,zoom=no' );

var myObj = {
    foo: "bar"
};
var s_myObj = JSON.stringify(myObj);

ref.addEventListener("loadstop", function(e) { 
    ref.executeScript({
        code: "var myObj = JSON.parse('"+s_myObj+"'); console.dir(myObj);"
    });
});
```

Comment: Edited the question a little.

Comment: If we execute this via following:  ref.executeScript({ file: 'myfile.js'}); instead of ''code".

Then I am unable to pass the jsonobject/variable. can you please tell the syntax for that. I tried above thing but it did not work.

I am accessing it like this:
'                    function myfonction() {  var myObj = JSON.parse(FCMtoken);
console.dir(myObj.value);
'